# Gitlab CI: docker not found

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to build my project using gitlab ci feautures.  According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196435/gitlab-ci-docker-command-not-found) question I've done everything correcly. This is my .gitlab-ci.yml.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - release
  - deploy

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
    - auth/target/

before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY

build:
  image: maven:latest
  stage: build
  script:
      - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS package

auth-release:
  stage: release
  when: on_success
  script:
    - docker build -f auth/Dockerfile -t "$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/auth" ./auth
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/auth"
```

But console prints out an error:

**Console output**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.7.0-rc1 (6e20bd76)
  on docker-auto-scale ed2dce3a
Using Docker executor with image maven:latest ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image sha256:067814781fbba30c17a86aa6159516660b6c210485ac9ac346d5101d6e4b70f0 for docker:dind ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image maven:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:3bc97dc2e7ba13887f5a850968419ad0e83fc482acd1cf0d9606882b665e39f3 for maven:latest ...
Running on runner-ed2dce3a-project-10090201-concurrent-0 via runner-ed2dce3a-srm-1547629674-aa23c547...
Cloning repository...
Checking out 10c9202f as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for default...
FATAL: file does not exist                         
Failed to extract cache
$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
/bin/bash: line 76: docker: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing your build stages.

According to your log, you fail on `build` stage, which is executed using `maven:latest` image, as it is written in your `yaml`.

But you also have your `before_script`:

```
before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
```

So, this script tries to execute on `maven` image and fails, because `maven` image **does not** have `docker` inside. Probably, you wanted to execute your `before_script` only for `auth-release` stage - it will work there, because `auth-release` uses `docker:latest` image, which in turn contains `docker` executable.

You are probably confused with your `docker:dind` service thinking it will provide you `docker` CLI in all images - that's not working so. `docker:dind` service provides you with `docker` daemon, but you still need `docker` CLI installed in all your images to interact with service.