# Docker commands failed in private runners

Tags: docker, macos, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I set up the runner on Mac through the [tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html#docker) and assign the job to it to run.

Below is my configuration in `.gitlab-ci.yml` based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196435/gitlab-ci-docker-command-not-found/65855484#65855484).

**OPTION 1**

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:18.09.7-dind
```

**OPTION 2**

```
image:
  name: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
```

Both end up with the same error in the pipeline.

[Failed Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VrOv.png)

Is there any configuration I am missing?

I have restarted the runner after changing `config.toml`.

**OPTION 1**

```
privileged = true
```

**OPTION 2**

```
privileged = true
volumes = ["/certs/client", "/cache"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have configured `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR` but your client is trying to use the insecure port (2375). When this is configured, you should set the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable to `tcp://docker:2376`. Alternatively, set an empty value for the certdir to disable TLS and use port 2375 instead `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""`

Comment: Below is my changed config, still getting the same error. Does the runner host need any other settings?

  image:
    name: docker:19.03
  stage: build-docker
  services:
    - docker:19.03-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

Comment: The runner's container executes the command ping 192.168.65.7 to test whether the DNS server can be reached.